# How do I change bash prompt in gnome terminal without messing up terminal title in Ubuntu 16?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

I don't like all long directory paths to feel up my terminal's space so, I truncate them through a python script. I have edited the .bashrc file and replaced PS1 to

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="$(python /home/vinay/bash_promt.py)"'.
```

And when I do that terminal's title doesn't work anymore. It simply displays `Terminal` Which is irritating. I can change the title manually by running following command in bash:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;CUSTOM TITLE\007"'
```

Is there a way to set terminal's title to the custom prompt which is being set in my bash.

Comment: You know there's a `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` variable that controls the number of directory components, right?

Comment: Also, [the `fish` shell](https://fishshell.com/) does this by default (and it has many other cool features too).

Answer (score 2):

For gnome-terminal, the terminal title is set via `PROMPT_COMMAND` which is defined in `/etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh`.

`PROMPT_COMMAND`, as defined in this script, does two things:

- changes the terminal title using the OSC 0 escape sequence (`\033]0;NEW_TITLE\007`),
- changes the terminal's notion of the current directory using the OSC 7 escape sequence (`\033]7;NEW_CURRENT_DIRECTORY\007`, this is factored out to the `__vte_osc7` function).

Should you remove the second one from your `PROMPT_COMMAND`, your newly opened terminal windows or tabs wouldn't open in the directory where you were standing in the previous terminal. Most likely you don't want this.

So, in your shell startup scripts, after sourcing `vte-2.91.sh` you have to construct your preferred `PROMPT_COMMAND` that sets the title in a similar manner to `vte-2.91.sh`, and sets the current working directory exactly as it's done by default.

I'm not aware of any way to refer to `PS1`'s resolved value (that is, after substituting the username and such) inside `PROMPT_COMMAND` or anywhere else (let alone filter out the escape sequences such as color changes). If you wish to see the same string in your prompt and in the window title, I believe you need to duplicate the construction of that string for `PS1` and `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

open  `~/.bashrc` . Find the line that says:

```
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

Comment out this line, by putting a `#` character in front of it:

```
# PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

Now add this line (you may want to put it just after the commented-out line):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;Custom Name\007"'
```

Replace **`Custom Name`** with whatever you want to change the Terminal title to be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope! This doesn't work at all. Same command I've mention in my question only. I believe you didn't get my question correctly. Firing up this command resets my bash promp, which I don't want.

Comment: if i am not wrong you said that you can change title by running `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;Custom Name\007"'` . If that's the case than if you take a moment to read my answer carefully you will see that i asked you to add that line to your `~/.bashrc` file. hope you won't mind giving it a shot.

Comment: No offence!! But I tried the command before posting the question here.

Comment: dude when you run `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;CUSTOM TITLE\007"'` does it changed your title.

Comment: Yes bro it changes title as I said in question but then it restores original bash prompt.

Comment: Ok now did you tried to comment `PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"` this line in your `~/.bashrc` file and just below it put this line `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;CUSTOM TITLE\007"'` . if you have tried and it didn't work than put it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The escape sequence to use is **ESC]2;new titleBEL** where **ESC** and **BEL** are the escape and bell characters. Like `\[\e]2;NEWTITLE\a\]`. Using #Bash escape sequences, changing the title in your prompt looks like:

`export PS1='\[\e]2;new title\a\]prompt > '` [doc ref](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Colors)

So an example of a multi-color truncated bash prompt that also has a custom terminal title is:

`export PS1='\[\e]2;$PWD\a\]\e[93m$USER\e[97m@\e[90m$HOSTNAME \e[93m$ \e[0m'`

In that example the terminal title will always reflect the present working directory (`$PWD`) and the terminal prompt will always look like the following regardless of what directory you are in: `user@hostname $`.

You can replace `$PWD` with `CUSTOM TITLE` to make the terminal title always reflect `CUSTOM TITLE`.

***Update***
Be careful when not wrapping non-printed characters in `\[` and `\]`. It works without it and I've been doing it without them for years. However, as I found out today with some setups, it [can cause some issues](https://superuser.com/questions/382456/why-does-this-bash-prompt-sometimes-keep-part-of-previous-commands-when-scrollin) in terminal. Below is a cleaner version using variables and wrapping the color codes:

```
T_YELLOW='\[\e[93m\]'
T_WHITE='\[\e[97m\]'
T_GRAY='\[\e[90m\]'
T_DEFAULT='\[\e[0m\]'
T_TITLE='\[\e]2;$PWD\a\]'
export PS1="${T_TITLE}${T_YELLOW}$USER${T_WHITE}@${T_GRAY}$HOSTNAME${T_YELLOW} $ ${T_DEFAULT}"
```